# Laravel master slave exceptions

Tags: laravel-4

I have a laravel app running and a master slave implementation. the master is used for writing and the slave is used for reading. However how do we work with sessions if we write to session table and grab from sessions table right after user is logged in? Is there anyway we can make certain read requests to the master instead?

Answer (score 0):

If I inderstood the question right, you could use the DB::on method described in: [Specifying The Query Connection](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#basic-usage)